# Is IDFA working correctly in iOS 16 beta?

Tags: ios, apptrackingtransparency

When updating to iOS 16 beta, a problem has been found that IDFA was not handled properly.

- IDFA is unconditionally renewed or
- IDFA value is returned as "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" even though it is authorized.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

Comment: Please add the answer of the question you asked in Apple Developer Forum https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/709051